# Project structure

Tags: views, blocks, 8

I was wondering what would be the best way to setup a Drupal 8 website that has about 15 mostly static pages in three languages? Static pages are somewhat similar but do contain different content.

Since it's multilanguage site and has different static and some dynamic content am i supposed to put everything in blocks to be translatable or is there a better way? 
Views maybe? I'm a little bit confused and don't even know if Drupal way is the good way to do it.

I know that my question is broad and not so specific but any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Enable the Language and Content Translation modules, create the content in one language as usual, then just translate everything into those additional languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an extremely broad question, so I can only give you a broad answer.

You don't create pages in Drupal like you might be used to from other CMS. You create *content*.

You need to change how you think about content to work efficiently with Drupal. First off, create your content, and then think about how to display it.

The closest to creating pages is creating nodes/content. Go to /node/add (or Manage > Content > Add content) and create a few pieces of content, for example of type Page. Make sure you enable the content translation module and add your languages so that you can translate it.

Each node (technical term)/piece of content is by default visible at node/ID or an alias that you define. That's your "page". But you can also create a view to create a list of content somewhere, based on some conditions.

Blocks are used when you want to place a certain piece of content into one of the block regions on all/many pages.

Do that, and then come back and ask more specific questions.

Comment: Thank you very much Berdir. I did this already. I do understand the philosophy of creating content, at least basics, but my confusion comes from not knowing if it's possible to represent HTML code as content. I know i can put stuff in templates also and basically put anything I want there but that can't, i guess, be translated if it's not formalised as Drupal content. I'm seeking a way to wrap my HTML code in Drupal system so it can be translated and extended by blocks on some of the pages.

Comment: You can translate things in templates if you do it correctly, but as interface translations. You don't really want to do it. You can't transform html templates 1:1 to drupal, you need to identify patterns, structures, blocks.. and then create those. E.g. you create a theme with regions, then you have the main region there and other blocks if you have additional pieces of content. To structure your main content area, you can you the CKEditor in the body or multiple fields, or you look into the Paragraphs module, or something like Page Manager.

Comment: Keep in mind that Drupal 8 is still alpha, and those modules and concepts are still being fleshed out. Drupal core doesn't offer much more than blocks/regions + wysiwyg/fields in the main content area.

Comment: Got it. I noticed that body field's text format, when creating basic page (content of type basic page), can be set to Full HTML. But when i do that i still get plain text with html tags. Could setting text format be the thing i'm looking for or it's used for some other purpose. If this is possible on entire project scope it looks like optimal solution.

Comment: Then that's because you entered html tags in the wysiwyg editor, you need to click on the source button to edit/enter raw html. Or create a text format that doesn't use an editor. Yes, you can use that, but it's recommended to use multiple fields or a project like paragraphs to better structure your content, that will make it much easier to manager translations, for example, compared to a single, huge textfield.